# Reference Link List Length Python?

Tags: python, list

**EDIT:** The terminology I was looking for was is called Cycle Detection. Thanks to @dhke for referring that in the comments.

I'm trying to figure out a better way to process a list of indexes and what it's length is if a list has a loop in its reference. I have a function that works but it passes the next index value and counter. I've been trying to figure out a way to do it by just passing the list into the function. It always starts as index 0.

Given a list, each node in the list references the index of some other node. I'm trying to get the length of the linked list not the number of nodes in the list.

```
# This list would have a length of 4, index 0->1->3->6->0
four_links_list = [1,3,4,6,0,4,0]
two_links_list = [3,2,1,0]

def my_ideal_func(list):
    # Some better way to iterate over the list and count

def my_func(list, index, counter):
    # We're just starting out
    if index == 0 and counter == 0:
        counter += 1
        return my_func(list, list[index], counter)
    # Keep going through the list as long as we're not looping back around
    elif index != 0:
        counter += 1
        return my_func(list, list[index], counter)
    # Stop once we hit a node with an index reference of 0
    else:
        return counter
```

Comment: Is `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` valid and what's its length? Nevertheless, you essentially need [cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection)

Comment: The downside of a linked list, of course, is that if you don't externally save the length you have to iterate through the find it.

Comment: Index(0) doesn't find the count of elements in the linked list

Comment: @dhke wanted to ask the same question. If he wants only the First time a 0 is found in the linked list it is a simpler problem

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso, no I'm trying to find the length of the list but the length of the links in the list. See the two_links_list has 4 nodes but the third is the 0 not the second.

Comment: @dhke Interesting I'll have to read up on cycle detection sounds like that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want extra data structures:

```
def tortoise_and_hare(l):
    tort = 0
    hare = 0
    count = 0
    while tort != hare or count == 0:
        count += 1
        if l[tort] == 0:
            return count
        tort = l[tort]
        hare = l[hare]
        hare = l[hare]
    return -1 

>>> tortoise_and_hare([1,3,4,6,0,4,0])
4
>>> tortoise_and_hare([3,2,1,0])
2
>>> tortoise_and_hare([1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1])
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set to keep track of all nodes you've visited (sets have very fast membership tests). And there is absolutely no need for recursion here, a loop will do nicely:

```
def my_ideal_func(list):
    visited_nodes= set()
    index= 0
    length= 0
    while True:
        node= list[index]

        if node in visited_nodes:
            return length

        visited_nodes.add(node)
        length+= 1
        index= list[index]
```

Comment: Interesting I didn't even think about using a while loop and returning once the length was found and a set to keep track of the visited nodes. That is even better as it will prevent getting stuck in a small loop within the list.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for recursion:

```
def link_len(l):
    cnt, idx = 0, 0
    while not cnt or idx:
        cnt = cnt + 1
        idx = l[idx]
    return cnt
```

This assumes the list loops back to 0.